# Subdivision and bevel not working even after multiple fixes

Tags: vertices, vertex-weights

So here is the bug :

[image: When trying a subdivision]

As you can see it looks like some vertices are unaffected by the subdivision modifier.

[image]

The same thing seems to be happening with the bevel modifier.

I created this object with booleans modifiers (which I applied) so it may explain why it is deformed. I tried merging vertices by distance (it fused 6 vertices but still didn't change the output). I tried applying all transforms (ctrl+a). I tried moving vertices around. Nothing worked.

Comment: that can be inverted normals. select all and shift + N

Comment: @lemon wow, that might be the fastest fix I've experienced, thanks lemon it worked I'll marked it as solved